# SQLite: how to SELECT a range of records?

Tags: c++, sqlite, select

I want to create a DB table and a set of commands for it. So currently I have

```
this->command_create_files_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (encoded_url varchar(300) UNIQUE NOT NULL primary key, file_name varchar(150) NOT NULL, user_name varchar(65) NOT NULL, is_public BOOLEAN NOT NULL, modified DATETIME NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )";
this->command_create_file = "INSERT INTO files (encoded_url, file_name, user_name, is_public ) VALUES (:encoded_url, :file_name, :user_name, :is_public)";
this->command_update_file = " UPDATE files SET encoded_url=:new_encoded_url, file_name=:new_file_name, is_public=:is_public, modified=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  WHERE encoded_url=:encoded_url";
this->command_delete_file = "DELETE FROM files WHERE encoded_url=:encoded_url";
this->command_find_file = "SELECT file_name, user_name, is_public, modified FROM files WHERE encoded_url=:encoded_url";
this->command_find_all_user_files = "SELECT encoded_url, file_name, user_name, is_public, modified FROM files WHERE user_name=:user_name";
```

(using [sqlite3pp](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite3pp/) syntax here)

I wonder how to `SELECT` some predefined `:N` (25 for example - no more) files or less from some start `DATETIME` point (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for example)?

Comment: You're always better off making your SQL code readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    fields_you_want_to_select
FROM 
    filesTbl
WHERE 
    DATETIME > start_of_range AND
    DATETIME < end_of_range
LIMIT
    25
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT 
    fields_you_want_to_select
FROM 
    filesTbl
WHERE 
    DATETIME > start_of_range AND
    DATETIME < end_of_range
LIMIT limit_num
```

Comment: but how to limit number of selected items?

Comment: You can use a LIMIT clause to set the maximum number of rows to return & ORDER BY if you want to control which rows will be returned